# GridView with all square equally sized boxes

Tags: android, gridview

In an experimental project I am working on I am trying to make a GridView that is wider then the actual screen and is scrollable both horizontal and vertical where all "boxes" are equally sized. For no I am strugling with getting the GridView to scroll Horizontaly and stay perfectly squared, and completely next to each other.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView` is not designed to scroll horizontally. You are welcome to try putting a `GridView` in a `HorizontalScrollView`, and if you are lucky, it will work.

`GridView` gives you explicit control over the size of columns, in the form of attributes like `android:columnWidth`. The heights of the rows are based upon what you put into the rows -- it is up to you, therefore, to ensure that you set your column width to be the same as the row height.

All that being said, please bear in mind that the built-in widgets and containers are not designed to handle every possible scenario. Depending upon what you are doing, you may be better served either trying a different approach (e.g., using a 2D game engine that supports the notion of horizontally and vertically scrolling maps) or creating your own widgets that meet your needs.

Comment: And btw, do you know how Wordfeuds View is build up?

Comment: @Magakahn: Sorry, but I am not a game developer and therefore do not know the capabilities of the Android 2D gaming libraries.

Comment: @Magakahn: "do you know how Wordfeuds View is build up?" -- no, I do not, sorry.